# Replace unique values in specific columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this:

```
col1  col2  col3
Aba   xxx   yyy
bab   bhh   jjj
ccc   kkk   lll
Aba   xxx   yyy
ccc   kkk   jjj
```

Currently I am replacing all the unique values of each column for ex:

In `col1`: `Aba` gets replaced with `a0`,`bab` gets replaced with `a1`, `ccc` gets replaced with `a2` where ever it appears in the column.

Similarly with `col2`: `xxx` gets replaced with `b0`,`bhh` gets replaced with `b1` etc.

In short first column starts replacing unique values with `a0,a1,a2,a3` 2nd one with `b0,b1,b2,b3`, third column with `c0,c1,c2`.. etc - using this simple one-liner,

```
import string
df = list(string.ascii_lowercase)[:len(df.columns)] + df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).astype(str)
```

But I want to replace like this above method to only those columns which has number of unique values (`nunique()` function in pandas) lesser than suppose 50 and the values of rest of the column can stay as they are.

Looking for a solution using the above piece of code which can be changed to include this objective. My dataframe has millions of rows and more than `20` columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need:

```
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3
0  Aba  xxx  jjj
1  Aba  bhh  jjj
2  ccc  kkk  jjj
3  Aba  xxx  yyy
4  ccc  kkk  jjj

#check column for number of unique values
m = df.nunique() < 3
print (m)
col1     True
col2    False
col3     True
dtype: bool

import string
#first select all possible codes and then only by condition
c = np.array(list(string.ascii_lowercase))[:len(df.columns)][m]

#apply solution only for columns by condition
df.loc[:, m] = c + df.loc[:, m].apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]).astype(str)
print (df)
  col1 col2 col3
0   a0  xxx   c0
1   a0  bhh   c0
2   a1  kkk   c0
3   a0  xxx   c1
4   a1  kkk   c0
```